# Node: converting utf8 string to base64 to upload as a Parse.com file

Tags: node.js, unicode, encoding, parse-platform, base64

I'm not sure if this question is specific to Parse.com or a problem with my (basic) understanding of NodeJS encoding.

I've been using Parse to upload text files - this is working great but it looks like the file contents are not UTF8 encoded (based on what I see from the data explorer in my browser).

Is there something I should be doing before saving the file to ensure the text is stored as unicode?

The code I'm using to upload is:

```
//test string
var a = '検索 • Busca • Sök • 搜尋 • Tìm kiếm • Пошук';

//trying to convert to base64
var buff = new Buffer(a, 'utf8').toString("base64");

var parseFile = new Parse.File("test.txt", {
    base64: buff
}, 'text/plain');

//saves successfully
parseFile.save().then(function() {
    var Test = Parse.Object.extend('Testing');
    var uv = new Test();
    uv.set('hello', parseFile);
    return uv.save(null, {});


}).then(function() {
    console.log('Saved');
}, function(error) {
    console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

When I look at test.txt from the data explorer, I see:

```
æ¤œç´¢ â€¢ Busca â€¢ SÃ¶k â€¢ æœå°‹ â€¢ TÃ¬m kiáº¿m â€¢ ÐŸÐ¾ÑˆÑƒÐº
```

When I try to use the same code above to save to disk using `require('fs')`, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data explorer you're using thinks the file is UTF-16 bytes encoded into Base-64 (this can easily be verified). You shouldn't worry, the data is correct, the representation is wrong. The data viewer isn't going to change your data, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although encoding using utf16le still doesn't give the right text in the viewer.. I also tried copying that text and decoding it back to utf8 without much luck. Am I right to be using `var buff = new Buffer(a, 'utf16le').toString('utf8');` on the extracted text?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by extracted the text. My line should replace the line above in your code. Why does it matter what the viewer shows? What is the data explorer?

Comment: You're right - I extracted the file using the request module and printed it to the console in sublime text with the data intact. So testing this on Parse Cloud code makes me think my issue is with the Parse.Cloud.http request (I serve the contents of the file up in my Parse express app and it looks like the results of the Parse.Cloud.http request is mangled...). Thanks! Now just to figure out this next bit...

Comment: If the utf-8 data is going to be put into a js string. You have to convert it to utf-16. `æ¤œç´¢ â€¢ Busca â€¢ SÃ¶k â€¢ æœå°‹ â€¢ TÃ¬m kiáº¿m â€¢ ÐŸÐ¾ÑˆÑƒÐº`` is what you get if JS interprets your string as utf-16 when it's actually utf-8.

Comment: Yep you're right - finally figured this out - none of the converting between utf16le and utf8 worked in Parse for some reason. Got it to work by taking the buffer from the response object directly and converting that to utf8.